# How can I manage repeatable text in my controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing some simple validation inside my controller. I keep repeating the text in quotes below:

```
if (!validate)
{
    _MyServices.Notifier.Error
        ("There are some errors. Please correct them and 
        submit this Form again.");
    return false;
}
```

_MyServices is just a call to an API I utilize to, amongst other things, display a notification for errors in a specific part of my view. This is just an example.

What I would like to do is keep a string somewhere so I don't have to copy this every single time and it's in one place where one change is all that is needed.

I am not good with this stuff, so how would I go about doing that in my controller? Or maybe in a separate file that multiple controller's can call to? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a resource file to store your string, then it can be referenced through C# itself.

Also this lends itself to localization of your application in the future.

To create a resource file just right click on your folder, and add new item. Then select Resource File, it should have the extention .resx

Once created you can add a Key in the left column, and the second column contains the string.

[image]

Make sure you set your access modifier to Public.

Then from within your code you need to reference the default namespace for the Resource file which is the same namespace as any class created within the same folder.

So if you were to create a resource file in a Resources directory of your application for example then you would reference the namespace like this.

```
using MyApp.Resources;
```

Then you would need to reference the specific string in your application like this. This uses the example where you named the resource file "MyResources.resx"

```
MyResources.Error;
```

The resource file creates a static set of properties that use your Key for the string. The key value you enter cannot have spaces in it but can contain some symbols.

Comment: I've already got localization covered in another manner. Trying to get the code right for creating a string I can use inside the controller.

Comment: Yes, a resource file will do what you're asking. I was just adding that you can use it for localization as well if you wanted.

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, but could you give me an example of a) what code would be in the resource file and b) how I would call it in the controller using the example I gave above? Thanks!